# How do I stop Facebook iPhone app from notifications every time a friend does something?

Tags: iphone, applications, facebook

I see the "Manage Push Notifications" option in the app's settings, but there are only four choices for the notifications you can toggle on and off: "Close friends list activity," "Group posts and comments," "Tags you in a post" and "Mentions you in a comment."

My problem is that I'm getting notifications every time friends (usually close friends, not always!) post anything on their profile. I'm also getting notifications when someone leaves a comment on a post after I do (regardless of whose post it is). I don't see options to turn these things on and off but they're driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it-- turns out there's a whole DIFFERENT set of notification prefs in the Settings app. (What a crappy app!) So I can turn them off there...

Comment: crappy? I'd have to agree with you, and would add horrible to that. One would think they could have the best mobile app in existence, but apparently not.

Comment: @Eric: it's well known that the Facebook app is a pathetic piece of crap. Thankfully [there should be an update soon](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/06/27/facebook-plans-to-speedup-its-iphone-app/).